# Limit autoincrement @Id to 6 digit in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, auto-increment

I have a model class
which as this auto increment id
which returns objectId of 24 digit.

How to limit it to 6 digit only?

**Model Class**:

```java
@Id 
private String id;    
    
public String getId() {
        return id;
}
```

**Controller Class**:

```java
ValidatorClass validation = new ValidatorClass();
    
Map<String, String> objValidate = validation.getExecutorInput(model.getLink(), 
                                    model.getUsername(), model.getPassword(), model.getSolution());

repository.save(model);

String id = "Request ID: " + model.getId();

return new ResponseEntity(id, org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the field to specify further restrictions, eg.:

```java
@Id 
@Column(length = 6)
@Size(max = 6)
private String id;
```

Furthermore, if you want finer control over the `id` before persisting an entity, you can add a method annotated with `@PrePersist` to your entity where you can truncate/transform the id as you need, eg.:

```java
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
  this.id = this.adapt(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem, if it solves your issue please remember to mark the answer as accepted.